# Newton's method - does it always work for functions that are close to the identity function?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, numerical-methods, dynamical-systems, newton-raphson

Since Newton's method for finding roots trivially works for the identity function $t \mapsto t$, I was wondering whether it also works for every continuously differentiable functions that is sufficiently close to the identity. To be more precise:

Is there $\varepsilon >0$ such that Newton's method (initialized at any $x \in \mathbb{R}$) works for every continuously differentiable function $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $|f(t)-t|<\varepsilon$ and $|f'(t)-1|<\varepsilon$ for every $t \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I think perhaps " attracting fixpoint " is something you need to study. Since newton works for linear functions , it is intuitve that it works where a function is well approximated by a linear function near its fixpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand why I got downvoted, but anyways, it seems that my intuition was right, I managed to prove the following:

*Let $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function such that $|f'(t)-1|<1/5$ for every $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Then Newton's method for $f$ starting at any point in $\mathbb{R}$ converges to a root of $f$.*

Proof: Obviously, there is exactly one $z \in \mathbb{R}$ with $f(z)=0$. For every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, denote
$$\widehat{x}:=x-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}.$$
We claim that $|z-\widehat{x}| \leq |x-z|/2$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Obviously, this is true for $x=z$. Assume $x<z$. By the mean value theorem, there is $\xi \in (x,z)$ such that
$$f'(\xi)=\frac{f(z)-f(x)}{z-x}=\frac{-f(x)}{z-x}=\frac{(\widehat{x}-x)f'(x)}{z-x}.$$
Since $4/5<f'(\xi)<6/5$ and both $f'(x)$ and $(z-x)$ are positive numbers, we have the following estimate:
$$\frac{4}{5f'(x)}(z-x)<\widehat{x}-x<\frac{6}{5f'(x)}(z-x).$$
Substracting $(z-x)$ we obtain
$$\frac{4-5f'(x)}{5f'(x)}(z-x)<\widehat{x}-z<\frac{6-5f'(x)}{5f'(x)}(z-x).$$
Since $4/5<f'(x)<6/5$, this leads to
$$\frac{4-5 \cdot (6/5)}{5 \cdot (4/5)}(z-x)<\widehat{x}-z<\frac{6-5 \cdot (4/5)}{5 \cdot (4/5)}(z-x),$$
hence
$$(x-z)/2<\widehat{x}-z<2(z-x)/5<(z-x)/2,$$
which proves that $|z-\widehat{x}| \leq |x-z|/2$. A similar approach works if $x>z$.

Finally, starting with any $x=x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and letting $x_n:=\widehat{x_{n-1}}$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, it follows that
$$|z-x_n| \leq 2^{-n}|z-x|$$
for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Therefore, $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = z$.

Comment: Congratulations, this is a very nice proof of a nice result with very weak assumptions. I believe that you will find this interesting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem#Methods_of_proof